# PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect 'test_app' because it is not a function. async def __call__(

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, quart

PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect 'test_app' because it is not a function.
async def **call**(

Here test_app is an isnatance of quart app:

```
# Create the Quart app
test_app = app.create_app()

def event_runner():

    policy = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy()
    loop = policy.new_event_loop()

    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

I tried seeting flad **test**= flase for test_app.

Comment: I fixed your code block and started to fix typos, but there are a _lot_ of them and I'm not sure what you intend to say in all cases. Please [edit] your question and try to fix them. Clarity and detail are important.

Comment: `pytest` collects everything that starts with `test_`, including `test_app`. You might want to rename it to something such as `app_under_test` to see if the error goes away.